# Compactness of the level set of a convex function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $F:\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ be a convex function such that for all sequence $(x_n) \to \infty$ we have $||F(x_n)|| \to \infty$ $(*)$, where we use the euclidean norm here.

Level sets are sets of the form $\{x : F(x)\leq c\}$, where $c \in \mathbb{R}$.
We know that the level sets are therefore also convex since $F$ is convex.

It is also clear from the property $(*)$ that level sets should be bounded. But how do we show that they are also closed? (and therefore compact)

If we know that convex functions are also continuous then we are able to prove this pretty easily, but can we do this without using that statement?

Comment: The level sets are closed because they contain all of their limit points. Can you see why?

Comment: @CyclotomicField I can't see that since I haven't really proved that all convex functions are continuous. Could you please elaborate your idea? Thanks

Comment: I convex function from $\mathbb R^d$ into $\mathbb R$ is always continuous.